# Automatically connect to closest Azure Cosmos DB location?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there a way, preferable in the Python SDK, but also just generally with any SDK/language or even just over plain HTTPS, to automatically connect to the closest region (by latency or some other metric) of a geo-replicated Azure Cosmos DB?

You can set the preferred_locations, but ideally I would like my app to automatically discover which region is the closest and connect to that (and fail over to another one if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update on this: The missing feature/switch is called `ApplicationRegion` which is already present in the .NET SDK. There is now a feature request on GitHub to add this to the Python SDK as well: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues/15685

Answer (score 0):

As i know only way is to set the prefered location, preferredLocations must be specified for high availability.

**`EnableEndpointDiscovery`** along with **`PreferredLocations`** allows you to leverage Cosmos DB failover capabilities.

If you set the value of this **`EnableEndpointDiscovery`** is true, the SDK will automatically discover the current write and read regions to ensure requests are sent to the correct region based on the regions specified in the **`PreferredLocations`** property

Comment: That was my hope about `EnableEndpointDiscovery` as well ;-) But turned out, the default for that is already True and it doesn't really seem to do anything. And even for this to have any effect, you already need to have PreferredLocations populated. Which is exactly what I dont want to do